# Implicit NA's making a table in the Tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, reshape2

I am running into an error message when trying to create a table using `tidyverse`. The error message reads

> "Factor Com.Race contains implicit NA, consider using
>   forcats::fct_explicit_na".

I am noob when it comes to the tidyverse. So I haven't been able to try much.

```
Major_A <- rep("Major A", times=150)
set.seed(1984)
gender <- sample(c("Female","Male"), prob=c(.95,.05),size=150, replace=T)
race.asian <- sample(c("Y","N"),prob= c(.01,.99),size=150, replace=T)
race.black <- sample(c("Y","N"),prob= c(.1,.9),size=150, replace=T)
race.AmInd <- sample(c("Y","N"),prob= c(.01,.99),size=150, replace=T)
race.hawa <- sample(c("Y","N"),prob= c(.01,.99),size=150, replace=T)
race.hisp <- sample(c("Y","N"),prob= c(.02,.98),size=150, replace=T)
race.white <- sample(c("Y","N"),prob=c(.8,.2),size=150,replace=T)
race.NotR <- sample(c("Y","N"),prob=c(.01,.98),size=150,replace=T)
degree <- sample(c("BA","MAT"),prob=c(.9,.1),size=150,replace=T)

enroll <- data.frame(Major_A,gender,race.asian,race.black,race.AmInd,race.hawa,race.hisp,race.white, race.NotR, degree)

multi.race_fun <- function(dat,startr,endr){
  dat$multi <- rowSums(dat[,startr:endr]=="Y")
  return(dat)
}

enroll.multiR <- multi.race_fun(enroll,3,9)

# load comrace function 
com_race.fun <- function(dat){
  dat$Com.Race <- ifelse(dat$race.hisp=="Y","Hispanic",
                         ifelse(dat$race.black=="Y" & dat$multi==1, "African Am",
                                ifelse(dat$race.AmInd=="Y" & dat$multi==1,"Native Am",
                                       ifelse(dat$race.asian=="Y" & dat$multi==1,"Asian",
                                              ifelse(dat$race.hawa=="Y" & dat$multi==1, "Hawaiian",
                                                     ifelse(dat$race.white=="Y" & dat$multi==1,"Caucasian",
                                                            ifelse(dat$multi>=2,"Two or More Races","Not Reported")))))))
  return(dat)
}
# run comrace function
enroll.comR <- com_race.fun(enroll.multiR) 
enroll.comR$gender <- factor(enroll.comR$gender, levels= c("Female", "Male"))
enroll.comR$Com.Race <- factor(enroll.comR$Com.Race, levels=c("African Am","Asian","Caucasian","Hawaiian","Hispancic","Two or More Races", "Not Reported"))

library(tidyverse)
gen_race.tbl<- enroll.comR%>%
  group_by(Com.Race, gender, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(perc = (count/sum(count)*100)) %>%
  gather(key, value, -gender, -Com.Race) %>%
  unite(Com.Race, Com.Race, key) %>%
  spread(Com.Race, value)
```

I would like the code to produce a table with counts and percents for all level of the `gender` and `Com.Race` variables.
[image]

Comment: Take a look at `cut`. Might reduce the usage of multiple `ifelse`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `gather()` from `dplyr` to restructure your wide-format data right at the start, then you can summarize the counts/percentages for each level of the gender and ethnicity variables. Using `reshape2::dcast()` at the end will give your desired output, but `spread()` can also be used.

```r
# toy data set
df <- data.frame(gender=sample(c('M','F'),100,T,prob=c(0.9,0.1)),
                 ethn.a=sample(c('Y','N'),100,T,prob=c(0.8,0.2)),
                 ethn.b=sample(c('Y','N'),100,T,prob=c(0.7,0.3)),
                 ethn.c=sample(c('Y','N'),100,T,prob=c(0.25,0.75)),
                 ethn.d=sample(c('Y','N'),100,T,prob=c(0.95,0.05)))

# gather wide data, group by gender/ethnicity, summarise, reshape to wide format
df %>% gather(k,v,-gender) %>% group_by(gender,k,v) %>% 
  summarise(n=n()) %>% mutate(perc=round((n/sum(n))*100,2)) %>% 
  mutate(cell=paste0(n,' (',sprintf("%.1f",perc),'%)')) %>% 
  select(-n,-perc) %>% 
  filter(v=='Y') %>% reshape2::dcast(v~k+gender, value.var = 'cell')

  v   ethn.a_F   ethn.a_M   ethn.b_F   ethn.b_M  ethn.c_F   ethn.c_M   ethn.d_F    ethn.d_M
1 Y 11 (84.6%) 69 (79.3%) 10 (76.9%) 66 (75.9%) 3 (23.1%) 28 (32.2%) 12 (92.3%) 87 (100.0%)

# using spread()
df %>% gather(k,v,-gender) %>% group_by(gender,k,v) %>% 
  summarise(n=n()) %>% mutate(perc=round((n/sum(n))*100,2)) %>% 
  mutate(cell=paste0(n,' (',sprintf("%.1f",perc),'%)')) %>% 
  select(-n,-perc) %>% 
  filter(v=='Y') %>% 
  spread(k,cell,fill=0)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   gender [2]
  gender v     ethn.a     ethn.b     ethn.c     ethn.d     
  <fct>  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      
1 F      Y     11 (84.6%) 10 (76.9%) 3 (23.1%)  12 (92.3%) 
2 M      Y     69 (79.3%) 66 (75.9%) 28 (32.2%) 87 (100.0%)
```